# Obtaining 17 digits precision of Julian datetime in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono, julian-date

I am trying to convert some JavaScript code to C++ for obtaining Julian datetime with 17 digits precision. The JS code is able to give me this precision, but its similar code in C++ is not giving value more than 7 digits. This 17 digit precision is absolutely needed because it helps to find Altitude and Azimuth of celestial bodies in realtime with a greater precision.

Here is the JS code.

```
function JulianDateFromUnixTime(t){
    //Not valid for dates before Oct 15, 1582
    return (t / 86400000) + 2440587.5;
}

function setJDToNow(){
    const date=new Date();
    const jd=JulianDateFromUnixTime(date.getTime());
    document.getElementById("jd").value=jd;
}
```

Calling this in HTML code as below
`<tr><td align=right>Julian Date:</td><td><input type=text id="jd" value="2459349.210248739"></td><td><input type=button value="Now" onclick='setJDToNow();'></td></tr>`  gives the value `2459349.210248739`

---

Here is the C++ code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

uint64_t timeSinceEpochMillisec() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

uint64_t JulianDateFromUnixTime(uint64_t t){
    //Not valid for dates before Oct 15, 1582
    return (t / 86400000) + 2440587.5;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << JulianDateFromUnixTime(timeSinceEpochMillisec()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This gives `2459848` as the value.

Question: How do I get 17 digits of precision?

*Note: The version of GCC I am using is MSYS2-MINGW-64 GCC 12.1.0*

Comment: `uint64_t` is not a floating point type. You should use `double` instead and look at [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) for help formatting the number when printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first look, I see three issues here:

1. Your Julian Date is a floating point number, so the result of your function should be `double`, not `uint64_t` which is an unsigned integer;
2. You want `t / 86400000` to be a floating point division, not an euclidian one which discards the fractional part. There are several ways to do that, the easiest, is to divide by a `double`, so `t / 86400000.0`. Some may consider that too subtle and thus prefer `double(t) / 86400000.0` or even `static_cast<double>(t) / 86400000.0`.
3. Even if you return a `double`, the display format won't be the one you desire. You should set it with `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision`.

Edit: I forgot that the most common `double` format has 53 bits of precision so about 15 decimal digits. You won't be able to have easily and portably more (some implementations have their `long double` with 18 decimal digits of precision or more, others have it the same representation as `double`). AFAIK, Javascript is using the same format as `double` for all its numbers, so you aren't probably losing anything in the conversion.